# not able to open image in tkinter window, task was to make a gallery of images using os module but some error occurs as nothing is displayed on Window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, image-gallery, python-os

The problem is my window is not showing any images that I want on the Tkinter window below is my code which I tried but some problems are occurring. the image folder is in the same folder in which the python file is and also some =thing with fp was coming up while trying to print jpg image. can someone explain what that is

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

gallery_root = Tk()
gallery_root.geometry("738x638")

for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk("/img"):
   for file in files:
      if file.endwith(".png"):
          Label(image=PhotoImage(file=str(file))).pack()
      if file.endwith(".jpg"):
          Label(image=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open()))
gallery_root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code won't run due to errors in the code - you have `endwith` rather than `endswith`, and you have a missing parameter with the call to `open`. You're also using an unsupported version of Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use generic `from tkinter import *`, but rather specify explicitly what you are using.

For image display, this code should work:

```
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filepath))
label = Label(image=image)
label.image = image
label.pack()
```

with `filepath = os.path.join(root, file)` for full path instead of `file` which is only filename.

Moreover, you make a lot of mistakes... Have you tried your code ?
For instance, `endwith` don't exist. Use `endswith` instead. And is your path really `"/img"`? Shouldn't it be `"./img"`?